# Lua runtime error on simSendData function

Tags: lua

After running the code below, I get:

> " Lua runtime error: [string "SCRIPT Quadricopter"]:78: One of the function's argument type is not correct. (simSendData)" as an error in V-Rep simulator.

```
simSendData(sim_handle_all,1,"zPosition",position,sim_handle_self,100,3.1415,6.283,0)
```

Comment: Probably, some argument is `nil`.

Comment: Please add proper tags, this is not just Lua in here.